# Как использовать данные из массива, без дублирования html?

Tags: vue.js

Есть код модального окна из примера на сайте vue.

Есть массив gameData, который содержит элементы типа ключ-значение:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        gameData: [],
        showModal: false,
    },
```

---

Как обратиться к элементам массива в модальном окне?
Я использовал v-for, но тогда окно дублируется. А без 
v-for обращение типа game.backdrop не работает.

Мне нужно, чтобы каждый раз, при открытии модального окна, в нем по новой отображались актуальные данные из массива gameData.

```
<transition name="modal">
  <div class="modal-mask">
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
      <div class="modal-container">

        <div class="modal-header" :style="game.backdrop">
          <slot name="header">
            {{ game.title }}
          </slot>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <slot name="body">
            <div class="modal-poster">
              <img :src="game.poster" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-description">
              {{ game.description }}
            </div>
          </slot>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <slot name="footer">
            footer
            <a class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
              <img src="https://img.icons8.com/windows/64/000000/macos-close.png">
            </a>
          </slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</transition>
```

Comment: Куча возможностей: слоты, бинд массива/элемента массива в пропс, vuex, шина событий, ...

Comment: Выбор оптимального способа зависит от общей реализации, и желаемых побочных эффектов. Абсолютно универсального решения быть не может, но ближе всего к этому vuex (в комплексных приложениях, отдельный стор на ui облегчает множество задач). Если же без vuex, то можно вспомнить о принципе одиночной ответственности, и использовать компонент со слотами / биндами на пропсы.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно что вы хотите получить - модальное окно отображающее конкретный элемент или список элементов в модальном окне.

В первом случае перед открытием вы должны определиться какой элемент будет показан в модалке - например распечатать через v-for список элементов, при клике на которые передавать в окно конкретный элемент, например:

```
<button
    v-for="game in gameData"
    @click="viewGame(game)">{{game.title}}</button>
```

Соответственно в методах описав openModal, например так:

```
viewGame(game) {
   this.currentGame = game;
   this.oepnModal();
}
```

Тогда в модальном окне можете использовать gameCurrent.title, gameCurrent.description и тп.

Не забудьте определить локально currentGame в data().